# Linux API and C++ STD vector

Tags: c++, linux, stdvector

How safe and correct is it to use a vector (vector unsigned char) instead of a character array (char []) when interacting with the file system using linux api (read,write)? Constructive criticism is needed. Are there any other alternatives?

I want to use this technique when writing a wrapper library (using classes).

Code example:

```
// This program was written to test the possibility of using a vector as a buffer
// for reading and writing to a file using linux api.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <fcntl.h>      // Linux API open
#include <unistd.h>     // Linux API read,write,close

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <unsigned char> buffer(10);

    buffer[0] = '1';
    buffer[1] = '2';
    buffer[2] = '3';
    buffer[3] = '4';
    buffer[4] = '5';
    buffer[5] = '5';
    buffer[6] = '4';
    buffer[7] = '3';
    buffer[8] = '2';
    buffer[9] = '1';

    // Open new file for writing (create file)
    int fd = 0;
    const char *path = "./test.txt";

    fd = (open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU));

    if (fd == -1) {
        cout << "Can't open (create) file!!!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Write to file from vector
    write(fd, &buffer, buffer.size());

    // Close file
    close(fd);

    // Open file for reading
    fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);

    vector <unsigned char> buffer1(10);

    // Read from file to vector
    read (fd,&buffer1,buffer1.size());

    // close file
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `write(fd, &buffer, buffer.size());` is wrong. You should use `write(fd, buffer.data(), buffer.size());` instead. The same works well with `std::string` also BTW.

Comment: Thanks. I have made amendments. Works really better. The file has become readable correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to initialize an unsigned character vector when declared?

Comment: there are [multiple constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) to choose from, to initialize the vector at declaration. How were you planning to initialize it?

Comment: Something like this: vector <unsigned char> buffer(10) = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regarding your doubts and questions

> How safe and correct is it to use a vector (vector unsigned char) instead of a character array (char []) when interacting with the file system using linux api (read,write)?

It's totally safe to use `std::vector<uint8_t>`, `std::array<uint8_t,const_size>`, `std::string` with API functions which expect a contiguous (null terminated in case of `std::string`) array of either `unsigned char[]` or `char[]`.

All of these classes mentioned above provide a `data()` member that allows to access the underlying data directly.

> Are there any other alternatives?

Yes there are other alternatives to manage these pointers more manually, e.g. `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, but usually you don't need them.

> I want to use this technique when writing a wrapper library (using classes).

That's a common, flexible and robust technique to create such API wrapper classes.

---

#### Regarding your example code

```
// Write to file from vector
write(fd, &buffer, buffer.size());
```

and

```
// Read from file to vector
read (fd,&buffer1,buffer1.size());
```

are wrong, because `&buffer`(`1`) doesn't point to the address of the underlying data managed by the `std::vector` class.

You'll need to use the [`std::vector<T>::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function to access that pointer to the underlying data:

```
// Write to file from vector
write(fd, buffer.data(), buffer.size());

// Read from file to vector
read (fd,buffer1.data(),buffer1.size());
```

> Constructive criticism is needed. Are there any other alternatives?

In your specific case it seems you want primarily text to be written and read from the underlying file. In this case I'd prefer to use `std::string` instead of the `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

That makes it easier to write stuff like

```
std::string buffer = "123455432";
```

for the data initialization.

Comment: As far as I understand (I am a beginner C ++ programmer) recently it is recommended to use the bitset container for performing operations on bits and low-level programming. This is true?

In this regard, there is an additional question for you. Can the bitset container be used in conjunction with the READ and WRITE functions of the Linux API?

Comment: @Blademoon If you have another question, write a new one please. But regarding the use of `std::bitset` you may have misunderstood something, or someone was telling you complete nonsense. As long you don't need or want to process any single bits you won't need a `std::bitset`, a buffer of contiuous bytes is perfectly OK, and what you need with low level `read()` and `write()` operations. To process a sequence of single bits from what was read, you can create a `std::bitset` afterwards using a single or some bytes from the buffer.

Comment: Thanks again. I will create a new question.